# What are the differences between Manim and VPython (Web VPython) for 2D or 3D animations?

Tags: vpython, manim

What are the main differences between Manim and VPython (Web VPython) for 2D or 3D animations from a user perspective?  In other words, what can be accomplished in one but not the other?
Which is most popular for math or physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of VPython but have never used Manim. Assuming that you do know something about Manim, I suggest that you look at the sample Web VPython programs available at webvpython.org. (Note that you can also use the vpython module with installed Python.) Another possibility is to post to the VPython (https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users) or Web VPython (https://groups.google.com/g/glowscript-users) forums. One difference is that it looks to me from a quick view of the Manim site that one uses it with installed Python to produce math animations that likely get posted to YouTube, whereas the Web VPython version lets you write programs that others can view without installing any software, and they can zoom, rotate, and pan the 3D animation. Another possible difference is that Manim represents itself as enabling math animations, whereas the DNA of VPython is to do vector computations in domains such as physics that produce as a side effect navigable real-time 3D animations.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. The main difference of sharing with other users seems like a major advantage of Web VPython.  At the risk of violating stackoverflow guidelines, I have a follow-up question that might be easily answered.  It seems like VPython was used by many universities in physics classes; is that still true today?

Comment: Yes. VPython is used in physics classes at various levels. It is used even in university intro physics classes that use the textbook "Matter & Interactions" by Ruth Chabay and me which offers a serious introduction to computational modeling, something that is central to all of STEM but way underrepresented in STEM courses. A huge advantage of Web VPython for the intro course is that the student doesn't have to install any software, nor be familiar with folders and files and file extensions.